# Display text in as you hover over different parts of a chart

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 donut charts in my application and I was wondering if it is possible to display text in the middle empty space as i hover over different parts of the donut charts. For instance both charts have different colours and each have their own percentage. So for instance if i hover over a certain color of the chart I would want to display a text in the middle. I was wondering what is the best way to do this as i am very bad with css and i do not want to do a simple hover over if there is better ways of doing this. Also if we are not hovering over the chart no text should be displayed.

Here is my code

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['rat', 30],
            ['bat', 50],
        ],
        type : 'donut'

    },
       legend: {
        show: false
    },       


});


var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#chart1",
       size: {
        height: 200,
        width: 450
    },
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['cat', 50],
            ['mat', 50],
        ],
        type : 'donut'

    },
      legend: {
        show: false
    },


});
```

This is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lccmvysr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [reference](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onmouseover), you can specify `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` handlers to `c3.generate`, which also get an element under cursor in arguments, then you can show/hide some text in the center, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lccmvysr/1/